# Is there a way to connect Elasticsearch 5.6.4 to Power BI

Tags: elasticsearch, powerbi, kibana

my company is running an old version of Elasticsearh (v.5.6.4). Im not overly familiar with the Elastic Stack suite but I have been asked to start pulling data from it to Power Bi for analysis (PBI).

I have seen articles that allow for connection to Elasticsearch using an ODBC driver but I'm not sure if this applies to older versions.

Does anyone know if its possible to connect PBI to Elasticsearch v.5.6.4?

Alternatively, my company has Kibana, so perhaps there is a way to dynamically extract data from that without doing manual extracts?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Elastic Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-odbc-installation.html),
the driver version cannot be newer than the Elasticsearch server version. For example, A 7.10.0 server is not compatible with 8.2.3 drivers.

In your case, you can try installing ODBC Client 6.5.0 as it is the oldest version available.

But unfortunately it probably won't work.
[ODBC Cliente - Past Releases](https://www.elastic.co/pt/downloads/past-releases#odbc-client)

On the other hand, Kibana is part of the Elastic Stack. That's why it has an easy connection with Elasticsearch, which has a connection with Logstash. This way there is no need for manual data collection to use Kibana in your company's Elasticsearch version.